# How to fill the left sidebar of the LaTeX Forty Seconds CV template in rainbow colors?

Tags: latex

I would like to change the background color of the left sidebar of the Forty Seconds CV LaTeX template (https://de.overleaf.com/latex/templates/forty-seconds-cv/pztcktmyngsk) to some kind of rainbow colors (either a color gradient or stripes).

When having a look at the cls-file, I discovered that the color is set with the command `\colorlet{sidecolor}{<some color name>}`, but this is not really helpful. Does anyone have an idea how to do this?

Comment: Please add a [mre] to your question so it stays useful in case the external link no longer works.

Answer (score 0):

```
% FortySecondsCV LaTeX template
% Copyright © 2019-2020 René Wirnata <rene.wirnata@pandascience.net>
% Licensed under the 3-Clause BSD License. See LICENSE file for details.
%
% Please visit https://github.com/PandaScience/FortySecondsCV for the most
% recent version! For bugs or feature requests, please open a new issue on
% github.
%
% Contributors
% ------------
% * ifokkema
% * Bertbk
% * Hespe
%
% Attributions
% ------------
% * fortysecondscv is based on the twentysecondcv class by Carmine Spagnuolo
%   (cspagnuolo@unisa.it), released under the MIT license and available under
%   https://github.com/spagnuolocarmine/TwentySecondsCurriculumVitae-LaTex
% * further attributions are indicated immediately before corresponding code


%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%                             ADDITIONAL PACKAGES
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\documentclass[
    a4paper,
    % showframes,
    % vline=2.2em,
    % maincolor=cvgreen,
    % sidecolor=gray!50,
    % sectioncolor=red,
    % subsectioncolor=orange,
    % itemtextcolor=black!80,
    % sidebarwidth=0.4\paperwidth,
    % topbottommargin=0.03\paperheight,
    % leftrightmargin=20pt,
    % profilepicsize=4.5cm,
    % profilepicborderwidth=3.5pt,
    % profilepicstyle=profilecircle,
    % profilepiczoom=1.0,
    % profilepicxshift=0mm,
    % profilepicyshift=0mm,
    % profilepicrounding=1.0cm,
]{fortysecondscv}

\makeatletter

\pgfdeclareverticalshading{rainbow}{100bp}
 {color(0bp)=(red); color(25bp)=(red); color(35bp)=(yellow);
  color(45bp)=(green); color(55bp)=(cyan); color(65bp)=(blue);
color(75bp)=(violet); color(100bp)=(violet)}

\renewcommand{\drawSidebarBG}{%
    \AddToShipoutPictureBG*{%
        \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
            \node[
                rectangle,
                shading=rainbow,
                anchor=north west,
                minimum width=\sidebarwidth,
                minimum height=\paperheight,
            ]{};%
            % plot vertical red guideline
            \plotvline%
        \end{tikzpicture}%
    }%
}
\makeatother

% improve word spacing and hyphenation
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{ragged2e}

% uncomment in case you don't want any hyphenation
% \usepackage[none]{hyphenat}

% take care of proper font encoding
\ifxetexorluatex
    \usepackage{fontspec}
    \defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}
%   \newfontfamily\headingfont[Path = fonts/]{segoeuib.ttf} % local font
\else
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%   \usepackage[sfdefault]{noto} % use noto google font
\fi

% enable mathematical syntax for some symbols like \varnothing
\usepackage{amssymb}

% bubble diagram configuration
\usepackage{smartdiagram}
\smartdiagramset{
    % default font size is \large, so adjust to harmonize with sidebar layout
    bubble center node font = \footnotesize,
    bubble node font = \footnotesize,
    % default: 4cm/2.5cm; make minimum diameter relative to sidebar size
    bubble center node size = 0.4\sidebartextwidth,
    bubble node size = 0.25\sidebartextwidth,
    distance center/other bubbles = 1.5em,
    % set center bubble color
    bubble center node color = maincolor!70,
    % define the list of colors usable in the diagram
    set color list = {maincolor!10, maincolor!40,
    maincolor!20, maincolor!60, maincolor!35},
    % sets the opacity at which the bubbles are shown
    bubble fill opacity = 0.8,
}


%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%                            PERSONAL INFORMATION
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%% mandatory information
% your name
\cvname{Panda Bear}
% job title/career
\cvjobtitle{Panda Scientist,\\[0.2em] Panda of the Year}

%% optional information
% profile picture
\cvprofilepic{pics/profile.png}

% NOTE: ordering in sidebar will mimic the following order
% date of birth
\cvbirthday{\today}
% short address/location, use \newline if more than 1 line is required
\cvaddress{Park Ave.~1, 555 555 B-Woods}
% phone number
\cvphone{+86 555 555 555}
% personal website
\cvsite{https://pandascience.net}
% email address
\cvmail{panda@bamboo.cn}
% pgp key
\cvkey{4096R/FF00FF00}{0xAABBCCDDFF00FF00}
% any other custom entry
\cvcustomdata{\faFlag}{Chinese}

%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%                              SIDEBAR 1st PAGE
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% add more profile sections to sidebar on first page
\addtofrontsidebar{
    % include gosquare national flags from https://github.com/gosquared/flags;
    % naming according to ISO 3166-1 alpha-2 country codes
    \graphicspath{{pics/flags/}}

    % social network accounts incl. proper hyperlinks
    \profilesection{Social Network}
        \begin{icontable}{2.5em}{1em}
            \social{\aiOverleafSquare}
                {https://de.overleaf.com/latex/templates/forty-seconds-cv/pztcktmyngsk}
                {Overleaf Template Link}
            \social{\faGithub}
                {https://github.com/PandaScience/FortySecondsCV}
                {Github Project Page Link}
        \end{icontable}

    \profilesection{Languages}
        \pointskill{\flag{CN.png}}{Chinese}{5}
        \pointskill{\flag{DE.png}}{German}{3}
    \pointskill{\flag{GB.png}}{English}{3}
    \pointskill{\flag{FR.png}}{French}{3}

    \profilesection{Hard Skills}
        \skill{\faBalanceScale}{Sleeping almost all day}
        \skill{\faSitemap}{Eating a lot of bamboo sprouts}
        \skill{\faGraduationCap}{Relaxing rest of the day}

    \profilesection{Soft Skills}
        \pointskill{\faHome}{Looking Cute}{4}[4]
            \skill[1.8em]{\faCompress}{No need to specify further}
        \pointskill{\faChild}{Chillin' hard}{3}[4]
            \skill[1.8em]{\faCompress}{On a tree}
            \skill[1.8em]{\faCompress}{In the grass}
}


%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%                              SIDEBAR 2nd PAGE
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\addtobacksidebar{
    \profilesection{About Me}
    \aboutme{
        The giant panda is a terrestrial animal and primarily spends its life
        roaming and feeding in the bamboo forests of the Qinling Mountains and in
        the hilly province of Sichuan.
    }

    \profilesection{Diagrams}
    \begin{sidebarminipage}
        \chartlabel{Bubble}
        \chartlabel{Diagrams}
        \chartlabel{with}
        \chartlabel{proper}
        \chartlabel{overflow}
        \chartlabel{protection}
        \chartlabel{for}
        \chartlabel{labels}
    \end{sidebarminipage}

    \begin{figure}\centering
        \smartdiagram[bubble diagram]{
            \textcolor{white}{\textbf{Being a}} \\
            \textcolor{white}{\textbf{Panda}}, % center bubble
            \textcolor{black!90}{Eating},
            \textcolor{black!90}{Sleeping},
            \textcolor{black!90}{Rolling},
            \textcolor{black!90}{Playing},
            \textcolor{black!90}{Chilling}
        }
    \end{figure}

    \chartlabel{Wheel Chart}

    \wheelchart{3.7em}{2em}{%
    20/3em/maincolor!50/Chill,
    15/3em/maincolor!15/Play,
    30/4em/maincolor!40/Sleep,
    20/3em/maincolor!20/Eat
    }

    \profilesection{Barskills}
    \barskill{\faSkyatlas}{Wearing asian rice hats}{60}
    \barskill{\faImage}{Playing Chess}{30}
    \barskill{\faMusic}{Playing the bamboo flute}{50}

    \profilesection{Memberships}
    \begin{memberships}
        \membership[4em]{pics/logo.png}{PandaScience.net}
        \membership[4em]{pics/logo.png}{Some longer text spanning over more than
            only one line}
    \end{memberships}
}


%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%                         TABLE ENTRIES RIGHT COLUMN
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}

\makefrontsidebar

\cvsection{Working Experience}
\begin{cvtable}[3]
    \cvitem{currently}{CEO The Panda Way}{Start Up}{Chief executive officer, Head
        developer and yoga ambassador of 'The Panda Way' - A company from pandas
        for pandas.}
    \cvitem{2015 -- 2018}{Panda Scientist}{Bamboo University}{
        Reasearching the impact of adequate bamboo nutrition compared to
        conventional feeding methods.}
    \cvitem{2010 -- 2015}{Bamboo Broker}{Stock Exchange}{Continuously achieving
        better bamboo bangs for the buck.}
\end{cvtable}


\cvsection{Education}
\cvsubsection{Postgraduate Training}
\begin{cvtable}[1.5]
    \cvitem{2009 -- 2010}{Post-Doc Panda Studies}{Panda Academy}
        {In-depth studies on the impact of bamboo nutrition for young pandas and
        its relation to relaxing, sleeping and snoozing parts of the day.}
    \cvitem{2008 -- 2009}{Research Stay Europe}{European Panda Labs}
        {Spending one year abroad teaching european panda facilities about the
        newest findings and research in the field of asian rice hat covers and
        applications for bamboo as a material.}
\end{cvtable}


\cvsubsection{Study}
\begin{cvtable}[1.5]
    \cvitem{2006 -- 2008}{Master Studies Panda Science}{Panda Academy}
        {Focus: Advanced rice hat studies and nouveau rain-reflecting cover
        materials.}
    \cvitem{}{Master Theses ($\varnothing\, 1,0$)}{Asian Rice Hat Institute}
        {Impact of solar radiation onto rice hat cover materials with special
        attention to water resistance.}
    \cvitem{2003 -- 2006}{Bachelor Studies PandaScience}{Panda Academy}
        {Focus: Bamboo morphology and its usage in different craftmanships.}
    \cvitem{}{Bachelor Theses ($\varnothing\, 1,0$)}{Bamboo Institute}
        {The bambo flute: An underestimated instrument in orchestras?}
\end{cvtable}

\cvsection{Publications}
\begin{cvtable}
    \cvpubitem{Cooking: 100 recipes for lazy Pandas}{Me and My Panda Friends}
        {Panda's Culinary World}{2010}
    \cvpubitem{Pandastasia}{Still Me}{Bamboo Books Assoc.}{2005}
\end{cvtable}


\cvsection{Awards}
\begin{cvtable}
    \cvitem{2010 -- now}{Panda of the Year}{Panda World Forum}{}
    \cvitem{2005 -- now}{Face of World Wide Fund for Nature}{WWF}{}
    \cvitem{2000}{Winner of Bamboo Sprouts Eating Contest}{Bamboo Society}{}
\end{cvtable}


\cvsection{Extra-Curricular Activities}
\begin{cvtable}
    \cvitemshort{Relaxing}{Master the fine art of relaxing everywhere}
    \cvitemshort{Music}{Playing the bamboo flute in the 1st Panda Orchestra}
    \cvitemshort{Education}{Teaching young pandas to be more panda-like}
\end{cvtable}


\newpage
\makebacksidebar
% \newgeometry{
%   top=\topbottommargin,
%   bottom=\topbottommargin,
%   right=\leftrightmargin,
%   left=\leftrightmargin
% }

\cvsection{section}
\cvsubsection{Subsection}
\begin{cvtable}
    \cvitem{<dates>}{<cv-item title>}{<location>}{<optional: description>}
\end{cvtable}

\cvsection{cvitem}
\cvsubsection{Multi-line with longer description}
\begin{cvtable}
    \cvitem{date}{Description}{location}{Some longer and more detailed
        description, that takes two lines of space instead of only one.}
    \cvitem{date}{Description}{location}{Some longer and more detailed
        description, that takes two lines of space instead of only one.}
    \cvitem{date}{Description}{location}{Some longer and more detailed
        description, that takes two lines of space instead of only one.}
\end{cvtable}

\cvsubsection{One-line without description}
\begin{cvtable}
    \cvitem{Award}{One-line description}{Sponsor}{}
    \cvitem{Award}{One-line description}{Sponsor}{}
    \cvitem{Award}{One-line description}{Sponsor}{}
\end{cvtable}

\cvsection{cvitemshort}
\cvsubsection{One-line}
\begin{cvtable}
    \cvitemshort{Key}{Some further description}
    \cvitemshort{Key}{Some further description}
    \cvitemshort{Key}{Some further description}
\end{cvtable}

\cvsubsection{Multi-line with longer description}
\begin{cvtable}
    \cvitemshort{Key}{Some further description. Can fill even more than
        only one single line while still keeping the correct indendation level.}
    \cvitemshort{Key}{Some further description. Can fill even more than
        only one single line while still keeping the correct indendation level.}
    \cvitemshort{Key}{Some further description. Can fill even more than
        only one single line while still keeping the correct indendation level.}
\end{cvtable}

\cvsection{cvpubitem}
\begin{cvtable}
    \cvpubitem{Publication title}{Authors}{Journal}{Year}
    \cvpubitem{Publication title}{Authors}{Journal}{Year}
    \cvpubitem{Publication title that is spanning over multiple lines and still
        does not look too bad}{Authors}{Journal}{Year}
\end{cvtable}

\cvsignature

\end{document}
```

[image]